# Change build root directory in VSCode

Tags: overleaf, input, vscode, folders, latex-workshop

**tldr**: how to change build root to different path from main tex file.

Using VSCode and the Latex-workshop extension, I want to compile a document. My folder structure is as follows:

```
/workspace_folder/
    main_files/
        main_file1.tex
        main_file2.tex
        ...
    included_files/
        included_file1.tex
        included_file2.tex
        ...
```

A main file consists of the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   \input{included_files/included_file1.tex}
   \input{included_files/included_file2.tex}
   \input{included_files/included_file3.tex}
\end{document}
```

While a typical `included_file.tex` just contains some text and stuff. Whenever I try to run one of the main files from this, I get an error: File `included_files/included_file1.tex not found'. When moving that main file to the root directory `workspace_folder` and run from there, I don't see any problems. The question is: how can I make latex workshop look for subfolders from the main workspace_folder?

Comment: Have you tried `\input{../included_files/included_file1.tex}`? With the two leading dots to first change one dir level back/up.

Comment: Well, that works, but I'm collaborating with people on overleaf. On overleaf, everything needs to be referenced from the root directory. So changing all the file references like this will cause problems in overleaf.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you might try `\input{../included_files/include_file1.text}`. I've not tried it myself, but guess it should work with `\input`.

Since both of your directories with `main_files` and `included_files` seem to be on the same level, you first have to go one level back/up with two leading dots.

This should work for most OS. On Windows I'm not sure, but since your file paths use regular slashes for directories, you seem to use a Unix OS which should work fine.

**Edit**: The OP said in a comment that it works on his local machine but not on Overleaf. I've no personal experience using Overleaf, but logically, if you can't 'move' one direction up to change the directory, you have to adapt your dir structure in a way you can access the files. I would suggest creating your `included_files/` folder as subdirectory to `main_files/`:

```
/workspace_folder/
    main_files/
        main_file1.tex
        main_file2.tex
        ...
        included_files/
            included_file1.tex
            included_file2.tex
            ...
```

Then you could input the files with your initial command `\input{included_files/included_file1.tex}`.

If such a folder structure is also not possible on Overleaf, you have to check their specific rules regarding that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `settings.json` of vscode

```json
{
  "latex-workshop.latex.outDir": "%WORKSPACE_FOLDER%"
}
```

The default is `%DIR%` which means that the directory of the root file (in this case e.g. the `main_file1.tex`) is the directory in which the compiler is started. `%WORKSPACE_FOLDER%` changes the compilation working directory to the workspace folder.

cf. [LaTeX Workshop documentation](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#placeholders)